# How to strip whitespace from element in list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, whitespace

I read over a file, scraped all the artist names from within the file and put it all in a list. Im trying to pull out one artist only from the list, and then removing the space and shuffling all the letters (word scrabble).

```
artist_names = []    
rand_artist = artist_names[random.randrange(len(artist_names))] #Picks random artist from list]
print(rand_artist)
```

howevever when i print rand_artist out, sometimes i get an artist with lets say 2 or 3 words such as "A Northern Chorus" or "The Beatles". i would like to remove the whitespace between the words and then shuffle the words.

Answer (score 1):

First replace whitespaces with empty strings. Then turn the string to a list of characters. Since i guess you want them to be lowercase, I included that  as well.

```
import random

s = "A Northern Chorus".replace(' ','').lower()

l=list(s)
random.shuffle(l)

print(l)
```

Also, you can use `random.choice(artist_names)` instead of `randrange()`.

Comment: what does list(s) do?

Comment: @shahaadn it converts the string, to a list of letters.

Comment: couldn't i just do l=[s] wouldnt that be the same thing or no?

Comment: @shahaadn there was a small typographical error in my code (letters were not shuffled). I fixed it. As for your comment. `l=[s]` wouldn't work,  since it places the `s` inside a list, instead of converting it to one.